# php to ruby strtr and preg_replace

Tags: php, ruby

I am just learning ruby and would like to convert the below function to ruby from php

```
function stringToDigits($str)
 {  $str = strtolower($str);
    $from = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $to = '22233344455566677778889999';
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', strtr($str, $from, $to));
 }
```

I apologize for not explaining properly earlier. This is my first question....

I am having problem in converting it into ruby. This is what I did

```
class String
  def str_to_digits str
      str = str.downcase
      from = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
      to = '22233344455566677778889999'
      self.gsub('/[^0-9]', '')
      # here I am having problem to translate the whole string 'str' from 'from' to 'to'
      # I dont know how to write it in ruby
  end
end
```

Comment: And your question is? You've said what you want to achieve, but not what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: We expect you to show what you've done to try to solve the problem.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String#tr(from, to)`.
Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr

However, you are creating an instance method for string right now. You would call it like this:

```
"examplestring".str_to_digits("second examplestring")
```

But you need only one string, so you have three options:

```
class String
  FROM = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  TO =   '22233344455566677778889999'

  def instance_str_to_digits
    return self.downcase.gsub(/\d/, '').tr(FROM, TO)
  end

  def destructive_instance_str_to_digits!
    self.downcase!
    self.gsub!(/\d/, '')
    self.tr!(FROM, TO)
  end

  def self.class_str_to_digits(str)
    return str.downcase.gsub(/\d/, '').tr(FROM, TO)
  end
end

# calling the methods:
str = "examplestring"
result_1 = str.instance_str_to_digits
result_2 = String.class_str_to_digits(str)
str.destructive_instance_str_to_digits! # result overrides str
```